# How to fix "Undefined response in pagination" with Bluebird promises (@google-cloud)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, bluebird, google-cloud-pubsub

I spent quite awhile troubleshooting this and finally found that @google-cloud pagination seems to break when using bluebird promises. It works if I disable bluebird, but since the project makes extensive use of Bluebird Promise functionality, it would be difficult to remove Bluebird. Anyone know if there's another work-around? Or which module I should submit a bug report to? (note, this seems to happen in any of the pagination functions, like `monitoring.getDescriptors`)

```js
global.Promise = require('bluebird');
const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

(async () => {
  const keyFilename = 'lib/gcloud-auth.json';

  const pubSub = new PubSub({ keyFilename });
  console.log('topics:', await pubSub.getTopics().catch(e => e));
})();
```

Output:

```
topics GoogleError: Undefined response in pagination method callback.
    at fetchNextPageToken (/opt/app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/paginationCalls/pagedApiCaller.js:55:26)
    at Http2CallStream.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:93:17)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at /opt/app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:97:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
From previous event:
    at Paginator.run_ (/opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/node_modules/@google-cloud/paginator/build/src/index.js:167:25)
    at PubSub.Class.<computed> (/opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/node_modules/@google-cloud/paginator/build/src/index.js:61:34)
    at /opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:69:28
From previous event:
    at PubSub.wrapper (/opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:54:16)
    at /opt/app/lib/index.js:8:38
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app/lib/index.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

```
Node 12.14.0
Alpine 3.11.2
@google-cloud/monitoring v1.7.0
@google-cloud/pubsub v1.2.0
google-gax v1.13.0
@grpc/grpc-js v0.6.15
bluebird v3.7.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works with Bluebird promises in Node 10 (you can check it) but breaks in Node 12 because of this: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/pull/942

Since it only affects JavaScript implementation of gRPC (`@grpc/grpc-js`), you can ask Pub/Sub library to use the legacy gRPC (written in C++), which seems to work properly:

```sh
$ npm install grpc
```

```js
const grpc = require('grpc');
...
const pubSub = new PubSub({ grpc, keyFilename });
```

Comment: Thank you!! That's an amazing answer and huge help! Both solutions work perfectly (patching call-stream or using full grpc)

Comment: To ask the Pub/Sub team to look into this, one can submit an issue here for further investigation: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues